# app.set('view engine','ejs'); ^ TypeError: app.set is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Problem in the template engine in `express` validation

I m expecting to resolve my problem

**app.js**

```
const express=require('express')
const app= express;

const port = 5000;

//set template engine
app.set('view engine','ejs')

//navigation
app.get('',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index') 
})

app.get('/resgiter',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('resgiter')
})

app.listen(port,() =>
    console.info(`App listening on port:${port}`)
    )
```

error in the template engine

Answer (score 1):

You **missed** to invoke [`express`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) in second line of Your code:

Instead of:

```
const app = express;
```

You should provide:

```
const app = express();
```

and **forward slash** `/` in this snippet:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});
```

---

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const port = 5000;

//set template engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//navigation
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/resgiter", (req, res) => {
  res.render("resgiter");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.info(`App listening on port:${port}`));
```

---

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>ejs it's Awesome! ;-)</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**folder&file** structure and **console output**:

[image]

---

**browser output**:

[image]

Comment: thank uuh so much buddy

Comment: @RajaHammadAhsan19Arid953 You're welcome! Glad I Could Help You!;-) Mark/ Accept The answer if it solved Your problem !!! :-D